# what's DESCINIT's leading dimension

Tags: fortran, scalapack

I am confusing about DESCINIT's lld parameter.

I set a

subrows(int(full_data_dims_b(1), kind = 4), m_b, nprow)

subrows as defined

```
integer function subrows(global_rows, block_rows, row_procs)
    integer global_rows, block_rows, row_procs
    subrows = (global_rows / (block_rows * row_procs)) * block_rows + min(mod(global_rows , &
    & (block_rows * row_procs)), block_rows)

end function subrows
enter code here
```

My descinit is

```
call DESCINIT( &
    desca, &
    int(full_data_dims_a(1), kind=4), &
    int(full_data_dims_a(2), kind=4), &
    m_a, &
    n_a, &
    0, &
    0, &
    ictxt, &
    & subrows(int(full_data_dims_a(1), kind = 4), m_a, nprow), & 
    & error)
```

My program finally cause segmentation fault.

Allocating this memory area

```
dset_id_a = open_dataset(file_id, dsetname_a)
dspace = open_dataspace(dset_id_a)
ndims_a = get_simple_extent_ndims(dspace)
```

Comment: Please explain what is this DESCINIT. Where did you encounter it? What is your subroutine supposed to do?

Comment: I defined function as follows.

    integer function subrows(global_rows, block_rows, row_procs)
        integer global_rows, block_rows, row_procs
        subrows = (global_rows / (block_rows * row_procs)) * block_rows + min(mod(global_rows , &
        & (block_rows * row_procs)), block_rows)

    end function subrows

My descinit

    subrows(int(full_data_dims_a(1), kind = 4), m_a, nprow)

Answer (score 0):

[`Descinit`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-fortran/2023-1/descinit.html) initializes an array descriptor for ScaLAPACK, the distributed memory version of LAPACK. As the link explains `LLD` is the "The leading dimension of the local array storing the local blocks of the distributed matrix". Thus it is almost always the local, on process, first dimension of the memory allocated for the array for which you are creating the descriptor. Contrast this with `M` and `N` which are the global dimensions.

I'm not sure what your function is trying to achieve, but you probably want to look at [`NUMROC`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-fortran/2023-1/numroc.html)